# What are the advantages and disadvantages of this derived system of calculating points in hockey?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl

Currently the National Hockey League awards:

- 2 points to a team winning (whether in regulation, overtime, or a shootout)
- 1 point to a team losing in overtime or a shootout
- 0 points to a team losing in regulation

---

I have derived the following point system based on the NHL's:

- 3 points to a team winning in regulation.
- 2 points to a team winning in overtime or a shootout.
- 1 point to a team losing in overtime or a shootout.
- 0 points to a team losing in regulation.

---

One benefit to this derived system is that it offers greater incentive to win in regulation and discourages playing defensively when tied especially in games that are significant to the standings.

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of this derived system that I've failed to consider?**

Comment: BTW such system is used in [KHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_KHL_season#League_standings). I've tried to search online for some discussion comparing KHL and NHL from this viewpoint, but I did not find one.